# How to see only specific folders of the media library in the Foobar2000 library viewer?

Tags: media, libraries, foobar2000

I want to start using the media library feature of *foobar2000 v1.0* and added one music folder, which contains a couple of subfolders with music of different albums.
I restricted the filetypes to `*.mp3;*.flac`.

Now my problem is that I don't want all albums/folders in my media library. But I can't seem to find an option to remove a particular album from the library.

Do you have an idea what I can do?
I thought about adding just the appropriate folders, but that would take a ages because one can only add one folder at a time :(

Thanks
-Martin

Answer (score 2):

There's kind of a hack for doing this, according to the [Hydrogenaudio Forums](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=64151&pid=572641&mode=threaded&show=&st=0):

> > You could however tweak whatever media library viewer you use to ignore a certain folder.
> >
> > > I'm using Playlist Tree. Doesn't seem to be a way to exclude certain folders with this.
>
> That's probably the easiest view to accomplish this!
>
> In the "Criteria" box just add something like
>
> ```
> NOT %path% HAS "Z:\Music\Unsorted"
> ```
>
> or, say you were to name all your unwanted folders with a ~, you could then use:
>
> ```
> NOT %path% HAS "~"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the problem, however, if you open Foobar then select

The file menu/preferences/media library

In the window on the right you can select to add the folder that contains your music files. This is recursive, so it will add all child folders beneath the folder you select. one you've added your files, foobar will monitor the folder structure for changes. if you add music or delete music, foobar will update.

Once you have a folder structure defined, you can select Library/Album list from the main foorbar toolbar to create a list of all the music in your folders. From there you can create play lists.

Foobar is extremely customisable and a good place to fine information is the dedicated foobar forum hosted at http://forums.foobar2000.org/]Hydrogenaudio Forums -> foobar2000 You can also find a lot of information on the forums http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/175690-foobar2000-customization-topic/]Foobar2000 Customization Topic

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is, that I don't want to physically delete certain (sub)folders. Instead, the media library should essentially ignore these folders  (or the files in it).
Thanks for the forum tips!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it was not the case when this question was asked, but in the current version of Foobar2000, hidden folders are excluded from the library.

If you still want to access those folders but don't want to turn on "show hidden files" in Windows Explorer, as a workaround, you could create shortcuts to the folders you are hiding.